# Password encryption - c#

Tags: c#, javascript, md5

Trying to simulate a file upload using HTTPWebRequest. The client side is using Md5.js from this developer [MD5.js](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/)

In my C# code I am generating the encyptered string as such

```
public string PasswordHash(string password, string Key)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    HMACMD5 hmacmd = new HMACMD5(encoding.GetBytes(Key));
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] byteBuffer= hmacmd.ComputeHash(bytes);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer3.Length; i++)
    {
        builder.Append(byteBuffer[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return builder.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

The function from MD5.js being used is next:

```
function hex_hmac_md5(k, d) {
    return rstr2hex(rstr_hmac_md5(str2rstr_utf8(k), str2rstr_utf8(d)));
}
```

Using fiddler I captured the key when logging using IE as well as the encrypted password. The password generated by my code using C# and same key does not match that of what the JavaScript method produces. what can I be missing?

C# pwd:`5d2b9c906608d8381cef4c24ff045be7`
pwd as generated by web site using .js and captured using FIDDLER: `f79a31f85da55aa0e3aca07e06568709`

Comment: Post an example md5 hash generated by each method

Comment: FYI: Encryption and creating a hash are two different tasks.  You can test to see which of your algorithms is correct here: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure MD5.js is also using ASCII encoding? It looks like it is using UTF8

Comment: You are correct. I assume that just changing my encoding to UTF8 encoding in my c# code alone will not do the trick. let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

Name Space :

```
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Data;
```

CODE USING "MD5" :

```
   string pass = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(TextBox2.Text,"MD5");

   cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblname where email = '"+TextBox1.Text+"' and pass ='"+pass+"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.IO;


namespace Utility
{
    public class PasswordManager
    {
        #region [ Public Methods ]

        /// <summary>
        /// AES 256 Encryption 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputText">string InputText</param>
        /// <returns>string EncryptedText</returns>
        public string Encryption(string InputText)
        {
            string EncryptedText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputText))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(Keys.NullInputEncryptionString);
                }
                else
                {
                    EncryptedText = EncryptToBase64(InputText);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ExceptionObject)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return EncryptedText;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// AES 256 Decryption 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedText">string encryptedText</param>
        /// <returns>string DecryptedText</returns>
        public string Decryption(string EncryptedText)
        {
            string DecryptedText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EncryptedText))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(Keys.NullInputDecryptionString);
                }
                DecryptedText = DecryptFromBase64(EncryptedText);
            }
            catch (Exception ExceptionObject)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return DecryptedText;
        }

        #endregion

        #region [ Private Methods ]

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt string with AES-256 by using password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">Password string.</param>
        /// <param name="s">String to encrypt.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted Base64 string.</returns>
        private static string EncryptToBase64(string InputText)
        {
            // Turn input strings into a byte array.
            byte[] InputByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(InputText);
            // Get encrypted bytes.
            byte[] EncryptedBytes = EncryptValue(InputByteArray);
            // Convert encrypted data into a base64-encoded string.
            string Base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
            // Return encrypted string.
            return Base64String;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt string with AES-256 by using password key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">String password.</param>
        /// <param name="base64String">Encrypted Base64 string.</param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted string.</returns>
        private static string DecryptFromBase64(string EncryptedText)
        {
            // Convert Base64 string into a byte array. 
            byte[] EncryptedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedText);
            byte[] DecryptedBytes = DecryptValue(EncryptedBytes);
            // Convert decrypted data into a string. 
            string OutputString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(DecryptedBytes, 0, DecryptedBytes.Length);
            // Return decrypted string.   
            return OutputString;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt string with AES-256 by using password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">String password.</param>
        /// <param name="bytes">Bytes to encrypt.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted bytes.</returns>
        private static byte[] EncryptValue(byte[] Bytes)
        {
            // Create a encryptor.
            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = GetTransform(true);
            // Return encrypted bytes.
            return CipherStreamWrite(Encryptor, Bytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt string with AES-256 by using password key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">String password.</param>
        /// <param name="encryptedBytes">Encrypted bytes.</param>
        /// <returns>Decrypted bytes.</returns>
        private static byte[] DecryptValue(byte[] Bytes)
        {
            // Create a encryptor.
            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = GetTransform(false);
            // Return encrypted bytes.
            return CipherStreamWrite(Decryptor, Bytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cryptographic transformation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="encrypt"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static ICryptoTransform GetTransform(bool Encrypt)
        {
            // Create an instance of the Rihndael class. 
            RijndaelManaged Cipher = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged();

            // Calculate salt to make it harder to guess key by using a dictionary attack.
            byte[] Salt = SaltFromPassword();

            // Generate Secret Key from the password and salt.
            // Note: Set number of iterations to 10 in order for JavaScript example to work faster.
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes SecretKey = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Keys.KEY, Salt, 10);

            // Create a encryptor from the existing SecretKey bytes by using
            // 32 bytes (256 bits) for the secret key and
            // 16 bytes (128 bits) for the initialization vector (IV).
            byte[] SecretKeyBytes = SecretKey.GetBytes(32);
            byte[] InitializationVectorBytes = SecretKey.GetBytes(16);
            ICryptoTransform Cryptor = null;
            if (Encrypt)
            {
                Cryptor = Cipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKeyBytes, InitializationVectorBytes);
            }
            else
            {
                Cryptor = Cipher.CreateDecryptor(SecretKeyBytes, InitializationVectorBytes);
            }
            return Cryptor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt/Decrypt with Write method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cryptor"></param>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static byte[] CipherStreamWrite(ICryptoTransform Cryptor, byte[] InputBytes)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] InputBuffer = new byte[InputBytes.Length];

                // Copy data bytes to input buffer.
                Buffer.BlockCopy(InputBytes, 0, InputBuffer, 0, InputBuffer.Length);

                // Create a MemoryStream to hold the output bytes.
                MemoryStream MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                // Create a CryptoStream through which we are going to be processing our data.
                CryptoStreamMode CryptoStreamMode;
                CryptoStreamMode = CryptoStreamMode.Write;
                CryptoStream CryptoStream;
                CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemoryStream, Cryptor, CryptoStreamMode);

                // Start the crypting process.
                CryptoStream.Write(InputBuffer, 0, InputBuffer.Length);

                // Finish crypting.
                CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                // Convert data from a memoryStream into a byte array.
                byte[] OutputBuffer = MemoryStream.ToArray();

                // Close both streams.
                MemoryStream.Close();
                CryptoStream.Close();

                return OutputBuffer;
            }
            catch (Exception ExceptionObject)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate salt from password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">Password string.</param>
        /// <returns>Salt bytes.</returns>
        private static byte[] SaltFromPassword()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] KeyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Keys.KEY);
                HMACSHA1 HashFunctionSha1;
                HashFunctionSha1 = new HMACSHA1(KeyBytes);
                byte[] Salt = HashFunctionSha1.ComputeHash(KeyBytes);
                return Salt;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    static class Keys
    {
        #region [ Private Fields ]
        private static string nullInputEncryptionString = "Encryption Failed : Invalid / Empty Input String";
        private static string nullInputDecryptionString = "Decryption Failed : Invalid / Empty Input String";
        private static string key = "Test@2013Rebuild$Encrypt";
        #endregion

        #region [ public properties ]
        public static string NullInputEncryptionString { get { return nullInputEncryptionString; } }
        public static string NullInputDecryptionString { get { return nullInputDecryptionString; } }
        public static string KEY { get { return key; } }
        #endregion
    }
}

When Calling from your Servics



 /// <summary>
        /// Validate the password hash
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public void ValidatePasswordHashForUser(UserModels model, string entity)
        {
            string passwordHash = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                passwordHash = ValidatePasswordWithHash(model.Password, _objUserModel.PasswordHash);
                model.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("Exception from GetSaltAndHashForUser(): " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


  /// <summary>
        /// Validate password hash
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="passwordHash"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string ValidatePasswordWithHash(string password, string passwordHash)
        {
            string passwordHashGenerated = string.Empty;
            passwordHashGenerated = _pwdManager.Encryption(password);

            return passwordHashGenerated;
        }

 /// <summary>
        /// Generate password hash
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GeneratePasswordHash(string password)
        {
            string passwordHash = string.Empty;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                passwordHash = _pwdManager.Encryption(password);
            }

            return passwordHash;
        }
```